# Can someone help me to fix this error? "this.healthRecord.documents is undefined"

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm a beginner in Java and Javascript.
This Java API works already and is online.
I can't resolve this error `_this.healthRecord.documents is undefined`.
It's written in the console (F12) when I try to add a file in the patient profile web page.

I have also full access to the back and to the front code source.
The front code is in typescript (angular).

Here is the code part of the front for uploading a file :

```
this.documentsUploader.onCompleteAll = () => {
}

this.documentsUploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
  let documentFile: DocumentModel = JSON.parse(response);
  this.healthRecord.documents.push(documentFile);
  this.healthRecord.documents = this.utilsService.deepArrayCopyDocuments(this.healthRecord.documents);
  this.addingDocument = false;
  this.notificationsService.success(NotificationConstants.DOCUMENT_SENT_MESSAGE_SUCCESS, '', NotificationConstants.PROPERTIES);
};

this.documentsUploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = (item: any, filter: any, options: any) => {
  console.log('***** onWhenAddingFileFailed ********');
}


this.uploadForm = this.fb.group({
  document: [null, null],
  type: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
}

save() {
this.patientService.patchHealthRecord(this.healthRecord).subscribe((profile: HealthRecordModel) => {
  this.healthRecord = profile;
  this.notificationsService.success(NotificationConstants.HEALTHRECORD_SENT_MESSAGE_SUCCESS, '', NotificationConstants.PROPERTIES);
}, () => {
  this.notificationsService.error(NotificationConstants.MESSAGE_ERROR, '', NotificationConstants.PROPERTIES);
})
}
```

Actually, it's not possible to add a file, when I try to do this the file adding button select the file but not adding as a file list.